# Excel: How to make certain cells "constants" so that they are not incremented when pasting a formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to make cell A1 an input, column B an input, and column C to depend on A1 and column B, for example,

I have the value 5 in A1, and I want to set C1 = A1*B1, C2 = A1*B2, C3 = A1*B3, etc.

In other words, I want to not have to write 5*B1, 5*B2, etc. but have that be a user's choice. The problem I am having now is that even if I write the first few formulas for C1, C2, etc, and drag the "plus" sign (or paste special => formula only), excel doesn't note that I kept A1 constant, and will revert back to setting Cn = An*Bn, when I actually want Cn = A1*Bn.

Comment: Have a look at *Absolute cell references* in the linked question

Comment: Thank you! didn't see that duplicate because I wasn't sure what the standard terminology is.

Comment: Also consider using a _named range_, if A1 is some always constant value.  For instance, if A1 is acceleration due to gravity, 9.8 m/s^2, you would put 9.8 in cell A1 and hit enter.  Then select cell A1 again, and click in the box where it says _"A1"_, to the left of the formula entry area.  _"A1"_ will disappear, replaced by a blinking cursor.  Type _"grav"_ and hit enter.  Now when you want to refer to A1 in a formula, your can type "grav" instead, which can make formulas easier to read.  (e.g. if col B is time in acceleration, then column c, distance traveled, would be `=grav*1/2 B2^2`)